# Getting cdlatex to recognize mathmode in tikzcd or similar environments

Tags: latex, math

I'm using Emacs with cdlatex to write latex-files and I frequently have to draw commutative diagrams using tikzcd. The interior of a tikzcd-environment is automatically parsed as being in mathmode, however, cdlatex doesn't recognize it being in mathmode, so that, if I want to insert a math modifier, it tells me that this modifier doesn't exist outside mathmode, and if I want to insert a math symbol, it automatically puts it between dollar signs. So how do I get cdlatex to recognize that mathmode automatically holds inside a tikzcd-environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cdlatex seems to use `texmathp` to find out whether text is in math mode. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317314/270912) explains how to get `texmathp` to recognize environments as being in math mode.